# Norm under Gelfand map vs norm under left regular representation on $\ell^p$

Tags: harmonic-analysis, operator-theory, topological-groups, banach-algebras

Let $G$ be a discrete commutative group. Let $p \in [1,\infty)$ and consider the left regular representation $\lambda : \ell^1(G) \to \mathcal{B}(\ell^p(G))$; that is $\lambda(x)y := x*y$,
where
$$
(x*y)(g) = \sum_{h \in G} x(h)y(h^{-1}g)
$$
for $x \in \ell^1(G)$ and $y \in \ell^p(G)$.
It's well known that $\| \lambda(x)y \|_p \leq \| x \|_1 \|y\|_p$.

Now consider the Gelfand map $\gamma: \ell^1(G) \to C(\Omega(\ell^1(G)))$ defined as
$$
\gamma(x)(\omega)=\omega(x)
$$
for all $x \in \ell^1(G)$ and $\omega \in \Omega(\ell^1(G))=\{ \text{ non-zero multiplicative functionals } \ell^1(G)\to\Bbb{C}\}$.

**Question:** Is it true that $\|\gamma(x)\|_\infty \leq \|\lambda(x)\|$ for any
$x \in \ell^1(G)$?

I have shown that we actually get equality for $p=2$ and it might be that equality also holds for other values of $p$. I can't seem to find a general argument though. Interpolation arguments have not been helpful so far and I haven't been able to find a reference dealing with this.

Comment: Just to help with looking up things in the literature: the norm-closure of $\lambda(\ell^1(G))$ inside $B(\ell^p(G))$ was traditionally denoted by $PF_p(G)$, the algebra of $p$-pseudofunctions. During the last 10 years interest in these algebras was revived due to work of various people (Phillips, Gardella+Thiel, ...) on "$\ell^p$-versions of $C^*$-algebras" and I think their preferred notation is $F^p_\lambda(G)$.

Comment: There is an over-the-top way to give a positive answer to your question: by a result of Herz in the 1970s, whenever $G$ is an *amenable* group the canonical homomorphism $L^1(G) \to C_r^*(G)\subset B(L^2(G))$ extends to a norm-decreasing homomorphism $PF_p(G) \to C_r^\ast(G)$. In particular this holds for G discrete and abelian, and then in this setting $C_r^\ast(G) \cong C(\widehat{G})$ where $\widehat{G}$ can also be identified with the character space of $\ell^1(G)$. (If I cannot think of a more sensible solution, I will post this as an answer.)

Comment: I have a feeling that in the case of abelian groups Herz's result was already known, via interpolation theory; this might be in Derighetti's book on convolution operators but I don't have my copy at hand right now.